# FB Graph api not working in build apk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am integrating FB Graph API in my project using following code :

```
private void integrateFacebook(){
    fbLoginButton =(LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    mLoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile"));

    fbLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            Log.d("Facebook", "Facebook Login Successful!");
            token = loginResult.getAccessToken().toString();
            Log.d("Facebook", "User ID  : " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId());




            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    accessToken,
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            // Insert your code here
                            try {
                                String name = "";
                                String id =object.getString("id");
                                String img_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/"+id+"/picture?type=large";

                                String email= "";

                                if(object.has("id")){
                                    name = object.getString("name");
                                }

                                if(object.has("email")){
                                    email=object.getString("email");
                                }

                                if(object.has("email")){
                                    email=object.getString("email");
                                }



                                UserActivation.getsharedInstance(getApplicationContext()).setUserName(name);
                                UserActivation.getsharedInstance(getApplicationContext()).setUserName(email);





                                SharedPref.getSharedPref().setValue(getApplicationContext(),"img_url",img_url);
                                SharedPref.getSharedPref().setValue(getApplicationContext(),"user_email",email);

                                submitData(name,email,null,null,"1","facebook",img_url,id);



                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.d(TAG,e.toString());
                            }catch(Exception e){
                                     Log.d(TAG,e.toString());
                            }


                        }
                    });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id, name, photos, picture{url}, email");
       //     parameters.putString("access_token", token);
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();




        }
```

Now It is working in debug mode but when i try to run through build.apk it gives following error in log :
Request without access token missing application ID or client token.

How to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

In your debug mode you get somehow the Facebook app-related keys and after building the project, the build no longer reaches that. So you need to review your ini files, database connections and other stuff to know why are Facebook credentials missing after the build. Look at how are the credentials used and find out where they come from. When you know the answer to that, you should be able to solve the problem by making sure that the build app reaches the juices.

Answer (score 0):

The android key hash that you generated and entered in your app in the facebook developer panel must have been generated using debug.keystore. SO to make it work for release build you have to generate a release key hash.
Checkout the "Setting a release key hash" section of this [Official Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started)